# ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0' and etc Errors happend in Ubuntu Server14.04

Tags: error, audio

I am using Amazon EC2 VPC, but when I start the Blender I got some errors:

```
root@ip:/home/ubuntu/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64# ./blender -b

ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
found bundled python: /home/ubuntu/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.74/python

Blender quit


root@ip:/home/ubuntu/blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64# ll

total 162400
drwxr-xr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Mar 31 14:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 May 28 04:47 ../
drwxr-xr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Mar 31 14:54 2.74/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 113425328 Mar 31 14:59 blender*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  52736328 Mar 31 14:59 blenderplayer*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu       745 Mar 31 14:59 blender-softwaregl*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu      5404 Mar  5  2014 blender-thumbnailer.py*
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      4774 Mar 31 14:59 copyright.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     35147 Mar 31 14:59 GPL3-license.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     17997 Mar 31 14:59 GPL-license.txt
drwxr-xr-x 9 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Mar 31 14:59 icons/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      1591 Mar 31 14:59 jemalloc-license.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu      4096 Nov 22  2012 lib/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      4947 Feb 19  2014 LICENSE-bfont.ttf.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      3421 Feb 19  2014 LICENSE-bmonofont-i18n.ttf.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      3299 Feb 19  2014 LICENSE-droidsans.ttf.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      2396 Mar 31 14:59 Python-license.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      6180 Mar 31 14:59 readme.html
```

Answer (score 7):

Use -noaudio option works, like this
`./blender-2.74-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender -b -noaudio "Blender/ball.blend" -x 1 -f 1 -o //`

hope could help someone!

Comment: What if I'm using Blender as a Python module?

Answer (score 1):

As of this time Amazon does not current support audio with their ec2 instances, even though they did previously. Until Amazon adds Audio back to the kernel, the only option is to use the `-noaudio` flag, or look for a non-amazon AMI that has sound capability.

I know this situation is especially confusing to users since you can easily find an Alsa config, and why you are receive errors about "Card 0" (set in asound.conf). Unfortunately the AMIs do not have any sound modules in the kernel, and that includes the snd_dummy module.

There is surely an AMI out there built off of a non-amazon AMI that supports Alsa or Pulseaudio to allow Blender to satisfy the audio requirement, but it all depends on how important audio in Blender is to you, and Amazon has discussed adding audio back in the future.

EDIT: It looks like the Debian Jessie AMI does not restrict any of its modules, so you can get both sound and multimedia codecs as well.